# Python- How to retrieve the vertex set by its attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I am creating a graph with vertex and edges using networkx in python.

```
G= add_edge(vertex1,vertex2)
```

vertex1 and vertex2 are integers i.e.

```
G=add_edge(4,3),
G=add_edge(2,3)
etc..
```

Since, in python if we just give the edge list it creates the vertex and create the edges between the specified vertexes.

Now i need to add an attribute to the vertex of the graph i.e. i want to basically separate the vertex into groups based on the attribute.

Hence,  i can do

```
G.node[your_vertex]['attribute'] = value
```

to add attribute to the already created graph G. #as suggested by BrenBarn.

Since there can be many different attributes and different values,  how do i retrieve the vertex

1. By it's value.
2. By it's attribute.

Comment: Your code will raise a NameError if `vertex1` and `vertex2` do not already exist as some kind of object.  What are the objects you're using as vertices?

Comment: Actually i am using numbers i.e. G=add_edge(1,2) and so on..

Comment: Your original question was already answered, but now you edited it to ask a new question.  Instead, just make a new question on the site.

Comment: OKay.I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#node-attributes):

```
G.node[1]['room'] = 714
```

You just do `G.node[your_vertex]['attribute'] = value`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I'll try to apply and update the post very soon.